# Eclipse PDT turn off auto insertion of closing bracket in CSS

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, curly-braces, braces

Eclipse by default will insert closing braces "}" when you type an opening brace "{" for most if not all file formats. This feature can be turned off for most file types in Windows->Preferences but how do you turn it off for CSS files or braces that are inserted in STYLE sections of HTML files?

Comment: This post was maliciously downvoted along with all of my other answers going back 7 years. Please ignore the current -1 downvote, although I think this may be why my question was not getting much attention before posting a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS editor and the HTML editor are developed by [Eclipse WTP Source Editing](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/), not by [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). Currently, there is **no preference to turn off automatically closing of `{`braces`}`** in CSS (like there is in [Java](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-typing.htm) or in JavaScript).

Of course you can also open the file with the text editor, but this is certainly not what you want. All CSS editor specific preferences can be set in *Window > Preferences: Web > CSS Files > Editor*. These preferences are also used by the HTML editor for CSS parts.

There seems to be [no such feature request yet](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?longdesc=css%20braces&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&query_format=advanced). But you can [request this enhancement here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&component=wst.css&bug_severity=enhancement&short_desc=CSS%20editor%20preference%20to%20turn-off%20automatically%20closing%20of%20braces&comment=See%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/46982539/6505250).

Source code:

- [org.eclipse.wst.css.core](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.css.core)
- [org.eclipse.wst.css.ui](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.css.ui)
- [org.eclipse.wst.html.core](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.html.core)
- [org.eclipse.wst.html.ui](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.html.ui)

Comment: I reported bugs https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562878 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562877 about this.